# SYNTAX ERROR SQL C# Selectedindexchange issue

Tags: c#, mysql

Hoping you can help us check this error.
We are trying to populate a bunch of labels using this code, but just keep on getting the same error over and over.
I have added the code below and the error as well.

Hoping you can provide us answers, thanks!
I need help in checking on how can i use list to add values on Labels for our project.

for everyone who will reply, thanks in advance.

Error:

No output or value on the list, unable to change values on labels using list.

```
private void cboSelectedProdut_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> conts = new List<string>();

        if (cboSelectedProdut.Text != "")
        {
            PointofSALES sales = new PointofSALES();
            conts = sales.CallProduct(cboCategory.Text, 
cboSelectedProdut.Text);
            lblID.Text = conts[1];
            lblPrice.Text = conts[3];
            lblStock.Text = conts[4];
        }
    }

public List<string> CallProduct(string category, string param)
    {
        string table, product, param1 , param2 , param3;

        List<string> stacks = new List<string>();
        if (category == "Accessories")
        {
            product = "Accessories_Name";
            table = "tbl_accessories";
            param1 = "Accessories_ID";
            param2 = "Accessories_Quantity";
            param3 = "Accessories_Price";
            stacks.AddRange(Catt(product, table, param).ToArray());

        }
        else if (category == "Batteries")
        {
            product = "Batteries_Name";
            table = "tbl_batteries";
            param1 = "Accessories_ID";
            param2 = "Accessories_Quantity";
            param3 = "Accessories_Price";
            //stacks.AddRange(Catt(product, table, param, param1, 
param2, param3).ToArray());

        }
        else if (category == "Cotton")
        {
            product = "Cotton_Name";
            table = "tbl_cotton";
            param1 = "Accessories_ID";
            param2 = "Accessories_Quantity";
            param3 = "Accessories_Price";
            //stacks.AddRange(Catt(product, table, param, param1, 
param2, param3).ToArray());

        }
        else if (category == "Juices")
        {
            product = "Juices_Name";
            table = "tbl_juices";
            param1 = "Accessories_ID";
            param2 = "Accessories_Quantity";
            param3 = "Accessories_Price";
            //stacks.AddRange(Catt(product, table, param, param1, 
param2, param3).ToArray());

        }
        else if (category == "Kits")
        {
            product = "Kits_Name";
            table = "tbl_kits";
            param1 = "Accessories_ID";
            param2 = "Accessories_Quantity";
            param3 = "Accessories_Price";
            //stacks.AddRange(Catt(product, table, param, param1, 
param2, param3).ToArray());

        }
        else if (category == "Mods")
        {
            product = "Mods_Name";
            table = "tbl_mods";
            param1 = "Accessories_ID";
            param2 = "Accessories_Quantity";
            param3 = "Accessories_Price";
            //stacks.AddRange(Catt(product, table, param, param1, 
param2, param3).ToArray());

        }
        else
        {
            product = "VapeSet_Name";
            table = "tbl_vapeset";
            param1 = "Accessories_ID";
            param2 = "Accessories_Quantity";
            param3 = "Accessories_Price";
            //stacks.AddRange(Catt(product, table, param, param1, 
param2, param3).ToArray());

        }

        return stacks;
    }

    public List<string> Catt(string product, string table, string 
param)
     {
         string id, quantity, price;
         List<string> Products = new List<string>();
         Global global = new Global();
         string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE @pram LIKE 
@param ";
         MySqlConnection connection = new 
MySqlConnection(global.ConnectionString);
         MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", param);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pram", product);
         connection.Open();
         MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
         {
             while (reader.Read())
             {

                 for (int x = 0; x < reader.FieldCount; x++)
                 {

Products.Add(Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(x)));
                 }

             }
         }
         return Products;
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use parameters in your SQL statement for the names of columns, because they will get encoded as strings (which causes a SQL syntax error). Like `table`, use string concatenation to insert those values. (Also, you need a space between the table name and `WHERE`.)

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM `" + table + "` WHERE `" + product + "` LIKE @param ";
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(global.ConnectionString);
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param",param);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion sir, i was able to fix it using lucumt comments, it seems its a typo issue, sorry about that, i edited the code and error above, for a different issue, but still related to the same combobox, i am trying to change the values on 3 labels on my form, using list, but its seems like it won't work, i tried using arrays list and list<array> but i am not able to make it work, any suggestions will be appreciated sir, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's seems as a typo,you need to add a space before `WHERE`

Change

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + table + "WHERE @pram LIKE @param ";
```

to

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE @pram LIKE @param ";
```

Comment: Hi Lucumt, thanks for this advice, i edited the code for another error, which i am not able to change values of labes using list, i tried everything from arrays to list, but i am not able to complete the code, any suggestion will be pretty much appreciated, this is for our college project, and having a great trouble figuring this out, thanks lucumt.!